# React com Typescript : Erro em um map no array de imagens

Tags: typescript, react

Interface:

```
interface CompanyDetails {
 company: {
   id: number;
   name: string;
   description: string;
   whatsapp: string;
   instagram: string;
   email: string;
 },
 filesCompany: [
 {
   url: string;
   name: string;
   path: string;
   size: string;
   wallpaper: boolean;
   createdAt: string;
   updatedAt: string;
  }]
}
```

Dados:

```
"filesCompany": [
{
  "url": "http://localhost:3333/files/6f121ec40c15d7e3b0e07002483cca21.png",
  "id": 55,
  "name": "1.png",
  "path": "6f121ec40c15d7e3b0e07002483cca21.png",
  "size": "97473",
  "wallpaper": false,
  "createdAt": "2020-06-07T22:49:11.250Z",
  "updatedAt": "2020-06-07T22:49:11.250Z",
  "company_id": 24
},
{
  "url": "http://localhost:3333/files/e0b01fbbcd1082d373672752df14e066.png",
  "id": 68,
  "name": "1.png",
  "path": "e0b01fbbcd1082d373672752df14e066.png",
  "size": "97473",
  "wallpaper": false,
  "createdAt": "2020-06-08T01:49:03.141Z",
  "updatedAt": "2020-06-08T01:49:03.141Z",
  "company_id": 24
}]
```

Ao tentar rodar esse trecho de código:

```
 {company?.filesCompany.map(image => {
     <img key={image.createdAt} src={image.url} alt="Imagens dos produtos da empresa" />
     })
 }
```

Retorna esse erro:

```
FALHA AO COMPILAR
./src/pages/CompanyInfo/index.tsx
Line 199:17:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression
```

Não faço ideia do que se trata. A princípio, imaginei que era sobre a key dos valores, e depois até tentei colocar as imagens dentro de uma lista mas resulta no mesmo erro.
Estas imagens são para um carrossel e usei esse pacote:

*react-responsive-carousel* -> [link do pacote](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive-carousel)

Não sei se há pacotes melhores, mas curti este pela integração com typescript.

Link no Gist -> https://gist.github.com/Jackie098/c13d2a277cf97448d3533b1723d0a104

Comment: `{company?.filesCompany.map(image => 
     <img key={image.createdAt} src={image.url} alt="Imagens dos produtos da empresa" />
     )
 }`, sem chaves e com o `<` no lado do img, nao seria essa a forma?

Comment: Perdão, ao copiar e colar meu código, acabei n colocando o sinal: "<". Mas ao verificar o meu código, está tudo correto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Galera, resolvi aqui. O problema era só na arrow function, ao invés de eu não colocar nada ou até colocar um parentese em volta do "return", eu coloquei chaves, o que fez o programa esperar um RETURN explícito.

Ao invés disso:

```
 {company?.filesCompany.map(image => {
 <img key={image.createdAt} src={image.url} alt="Imagens dos produtos da empresa" />
 })
```

}

Eu deveria:

```
 {company?.filesCompany.map(image => (
 <img key={image.createdAt} src={image.url} alt="Imagens dos produtos da empresa" />
 ))
```

}

Ou até mesmo não colocar nada, mas ficaria sem quebra de linha e seria chato pra ler:

```
     {company?.filesCompany.map(image => <img key={image.createdAt} src={image.url} alt="Imagens dos produtos da empresa" />)}
```